# How to setFocus() on QListView in QFileDialog in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I've made my first small GUI program using PyQt5 for some data process for my work.

I have a problem - I can't make QFileDialog (to open file) with the focus on its QListView widget. (In QFileDialog class by default focus is on QLineEdit).

The best solution is to make new class from QFileDialog with changed setFocus settings and unchanged all the other.
It turned out to be not so easy because I didn't find how to adress to inner widgets of QFileDialog.

I'm new in PyQt5, couldn't find any solutionts even for Qt C++.

Thank you for any advices and ideas.

```
  class XFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):

       "magic code"


  file=XFileDialog.getOpenFileName(caption="Open",
                               filter="FITS (*.fits *.fts *.new)")
```

Comment: Why you would want to do that? That window is controlled by the OS and you should not modify the default behavior, otherwise your application will not  work as uses expected i.e. as a user you might want to type the name of the file directly. You could roll your own window if you need it to do something especial, but seems like a lot of work to simply set the focus in a list of files...

Comment: Program works this way 8) I need focus on Listview exactly after QFileDialog becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found the solution. Perhaps it could be useful for someone.

```
class XFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QFileDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setDirectory(progdir)

    def setVisible(self,v):

        super(XFileDialog, self).setVisible(v)
        self.setAcceptMode(0)
        self.setFileMode(1)
        self.setFocusPolicy(11)
        self.setNameFilter("All (*) ;; FITS (*.fts *.fits *.new)")
        self.focusPreviousChild()      


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None): 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def openFile(self):
        global progdir
        progdir=QtCore.QDir(os.getcwd())
        file=XFileDialog()
        file.exec()
```

.......