# PyQt5 QFileDialog - Highlight Suggested File in the QListView Widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, focus, qfiledialog, qlistview

I’m using PyQt5 on a Windows platform.  I want to present a QFileDialog to the user with the suggested file highlighted in both the  QListView and the QLineEdit widgets within the QFileDialog window.  The `selectFile()` method adds the filename to the QLineEdit widget and highlightss it, but does not highlight the file in the QListView widget.

I tried the suggestion in [How to setFocus() on QListView in QFileDialog in PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795777/how-to-setfocus-on-qlistview-in-qfiledialog-in-pyqt5), but I could not see that the QListView had focus and could not highlight a file with `selectFile()`.

In QFileDialog, is there a way to highlight the filename in the QistView and in the QLineEdit widgets?  If not, is there a way to highlight the filename in just the QListView?

Here is a minimalized script that shows the filename highlighted in the QLineEdit widget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir

class MyClass(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.DontUseNativeDialog
        self.openFile()

    def openFile(self):
        qdir = QDir()
        qdir.setPath('C:\\Users\\Slalo\\Documents\\VideoGates\\PVRTop\\Folder') 
        qdir.setSorting(QDir.Name | QDir.Reversed)
        qdirlist = qdir.entryList()
        self.setWindowTitle('Open File')
        self.setDirectory(qdir)
        self.setNameFilter('All(*.*)') 
        self.selectFile(qdirlist[1])        
        
        if self.exec():
            fname = self.selectedFiles()
            print(fname)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Why are you creating a *new* file dialog *inside* a QFileDialog subclass? Besides, I cannot test on Windows (on Linux it works as expected), but have you tried to use the *absolute* path instead of the file name alone? `dialog.selectFile(fname)`

Comment: @musicamante - I don't know why I created a QFileDialog inside another.  I changed the code sample to make if `self`.  I also added the absolute path for the filenames.  No change in result - still looking for a solution

Comment: Might be related to [QTBUG-47159](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47159). The problem could be related to the way QUrl maps paths, which is extremely important on windows since they still use that annoying (and *non-standard*) backslash separators. Right now I'm not sure that there could be a proper work around for that, except for using the `DontUseNativeDialog` option flag.

Comment: @musicamante - Good idea on the `DontUseNativeDialog`.  Unfortunately, it did not solve my issue.

Comment: It should work, try using the Qt library to get the actual path, with default classes such as QDir and QFileInfo.

Comment: @musicamante - I edited my question above to show the code that replaces the Python `os` with `QDir`.  I also added `DontUseNativeDialog` in `__init__(self)`.  Still no change.  I tried it in both Spyder and IDLE, but the behavior was the same either way.  It may be a quirk that is particular to Windows.

Comment: The IDE doesn't matter. Besides, you're *not* using the flag, that line is completely useless: you have to *set* it, with [`setOption()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setOption).

Comment: @musicamante - That's it!  I didn't set the `DontUseNativeDialog` correctly.  I've only used QFileDialog as a static function until now.  I'll answer the question with the working code so others can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing @musicamante 's patience, here is the solution.  The QFileDialog window looks a little different than the native Windows dialog, but that's OK - it works as intended.  Here is the corrected script.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

class MyClass(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self.openFile()

    def openFile(self):
        dirname = 'C:\\Users\\Slalo\\Documents\\VideoGates\\PVRTop\\Folder'
        fileList = os.listdir(dirname)
        self.setWindowTitle('Open File')
        self.setDirectory(dirname)
        self.setNameFilter('All(*.*)') 
        self.selectFile(fileList[1]) 
        
        if self.exec():
            fname = self.selectedFiles()
            print(fname)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = MyClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```